# How to give reference for one particular child from firebase ? how to read inside child? Check out my screenshot and help me to solve this error

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

[image]

I'm not getting data from firebase child **Moreim** (Moreimages) but remaining data shows in output
how to read Moreim child from firebase actually I'm reading data from secondActivity

I'm using viewpager for more images to display in one Imageview and I created Adapter, Adapter works fine it returning imageView but not displaying because I don't know to refer Moreim
Guys help me to solve this null error

```
  SecondActivity:
    
    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        DatabaseReference ref;
     TextView Gname,Gnickname,Gdesc;
     ImageView Gimages;
        private ArrayList<String> imageUrls ;
        private static final String TAG = "SecondActivity";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
            Gname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gettingname);
            Gnickname =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gettingnickname);
            Gimages = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            Gdesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.getdesc);
            imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
    
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
            String UsersId = getIntent().getStringExtra("User");
    
             ref.child(UsersId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasChildren()){
                        String name = (snapshot.child("Name").getValue()).toString();
                        String nick = (snapshot.child("Nickname").getValue()).toString();
                        // String imagee = (snapshot.child("images").getValue().toString());
                        String descc = (snapshot.child("Description").getValue().toString());
                        Gname.setText(name);
                        Gnickname.setText(nick);
                        //   Picasso.get().load(imagee).into(Gimages);
                        Gdesc.setText(descc);
    
                        for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                           imageUrls.add(data.child("Moreim").getValue().toString());
                        }
                        }
                    else {
                        Gname.setText("No data");
                    }
                    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewimages);
                    ViewAdapter adapter = new ViewAdapter(SecondActivity.this,imageUrls);
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

I'm having doubt in this part
 for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                           imageUrls.add(data.child("Moreim").getValue().toString());
                        }
how to read child Moreim ?

Error:
  Process: com.example.firebasesearchrec, PID: 5818
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.firebasesearchrec.SecondActivity$1.onDataChange(SecondActivity.java:55)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>>() {
                            };
                            imageUrls = snapshot
                                    .child("Moreim")
                                    .getValue(t);
```

Instead of

```
for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                       imageUrls.add(data.child("Moreim").getValue().toString());
                    }
```

**Reasoning:**
As far as I understand, you need a way to get an `ArrayList<String>` from a field in the snapshot. Aside from using model classes, simply passing `ArrayList.class` won't do, since it can't factor in the `<String>` wildcard. So in this snippet, a generic type is made of an `ArrayList<String>` which is then passed.

*I hope this helps!!*

**Edit:** Typo in field name.

Comment: Thanks bro replying, is there any method to refer that Moreim child which is inside

Comment: did you check the field name? I made e typo in the suggested code, fixed it now

Comment: Thanks bro I got it but I don't know what is GenericTypeIndicator ? where to use it, just tell me in simple manner

Comment: The `snapshot.getValue()` takes in a class. Think of it as a mold, firebase needs to know which data should be transformed into which class. In the case of `ArrayList`, there is only `ArrayList.class`. But as you know `ArrayList` can hold various types using `<>` wildcard. This is where `GenericIndicator` comes in. `GenericIndicator` can tell firebase exactly what type of `ArrayList` this is (in this case, `String`).

Comment: Thanks bro for replying and telling the answers